# How to draw at the current GPS location on MapView using MyLocationOverlay?

Tags: android, gps, location, android-mapview, mylocationoverlay

I'm trying to draw a custom gps-location icon. I'm using [`MapView`](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/index.html) and have created a class `MyLocationArrow` that extends [`MyLocationOverlay`](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html).

I override `drawMyLocation()` and draw a point at 100,100. But this is the coordinates on screen. How do I get the screen-coordinates from the current GPS-location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
android.graphics.Point toPixels(GeoPoint in,
                                android.graphics.Point out)
```

Converts the given `GeoPoint` to onscreen pixel coordinates, relative to the top-left of the `MapView` that provided this `Projection`.

.

Comment: Sorry, it's in MapView : mapView.getProjection().toPixels(in, out);