# Rotate a map marker when screen rotates?

Tags: android, google-maps, rotation, google-maps-markers

I'm unable to make my custom marker in an Android App Rotate when using Google Maps API v2. I want to show the rotation like it occurs in the Uber App. I've set the flat property on the Marker, but it doesn't help. Following is the snippet

```
Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.vehicle_marker)).flat(true).anchor(0.5f,0.5f));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by using devices bearing or follow this [tutorial](http://android-coding.blogspot.co.at/2012/03/create-our-android-compass.html).

Create a marker which is is perfect for bearing updates.

```
private Marker marker;

// Create this marker only once; probably in your onMapReady() method
marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(myLatitude, myLongitude))
        .flat(true));
```

Get the bearing updates by using [`getBearing()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getBearing()) method from [`Location`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) object

```
  if (mLastLocation.hasBearing()) {
     marker.setRotation(mLocation.getBearing());
    }
     //if following the linked tutorial
    // marker.setRotation((float) azimuth);
```

*Aware about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258365/android-getbearing-only-returns-0-0-trying-to-use-to-rotate-current-location-ic) also when you using it.*

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this

```
Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.vehicle_marker)).flat(true).anchor(0.5f,0.5f).rotation(180));
```